# Transform Integer list into moving sum list

Tags: apex, list

I have an Integer list, which has to be transformed into moving sum list:
[ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ]        => [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
[ 10, -10, 10, -10, 10 ] => [ 10, 0, 10, 0, 10 ]

But I'm struggling, how to set this up. Can anyone guide me through this?

```
public static List < Integer > getMovingSum(List < Integer > arr) {
    List < Integer > movingSumList = new List < Integer > ();
    movingSumList.add(arr[0]);
    for (Integer i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {

        Integer sum = movingSumList[i] + arr[i + 1];
        movingSumList.add(sum);
    }
    return movingSumList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in the loop exit. In case if **i** equals  **arr.size() - 1**, it will still not exit the loop, but rather try to access **i+1** element of an **arr** array, and that would cause an exception.

This is proper code

```
public static List < Integer > getMovingSum(List < Integer > arr) {
    List < Integer > movingSumList = new List < Integer > ();
    movingSumList.add(arr[0]);
    for (Integer i = 0; i < arr.size() - 1; i++) {
        Integer sum = movingSumList[i] + arr[i + 1];
        movingSumList.add(sum);
    }
    return movingSumList;
}
```